# join table in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, lcds

How can I show a join table in a datagrid in Flex using LCDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By table you mean a database table, right?

Join the tables in an SQL query on the server; then send that query back to Flex already joined.  Many people will turn it into an array of value objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you point me to any example/tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: Which portion do you need help on?  You can Google SQL Joins: http://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Join&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Well that is OK, but how to use value objects for joining tables?

Comment: You wouldn't use a Value Object for joining tables, you would use an SQL Join.  Query your database using any SQL you prefer and you'll get back a recordset.  Most people would turn that recordset into Value Objects using a loop.  Return the finished array of Value Objects to Flex. If you're using ColdFusion; you can return the recordset (AKA Query Object) directly to Flex w/o turning it into a VO.